# Need help using inheritance to accept derived-type parameters in a finite state machine

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, polymorphism, abstract

I've just started trying to use some abstract classes and inheritance to code a finite state machine where the states and the state machine can be inherited so that the framework could be used on different types of AI.

The problem is that the inherited classes keep expecting the base type of their parameters, not accepting derived types and I'm not sure if I'm going about it the wrong way or merely coding it the wrong way. (From my understanding, I'm trying to implement the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle))

The base code:

```
public abstract class State {
    public abstract void BeginState(StateMachine stateMachine);
    public abstract void UpdateState(StateMachine stateMachine);
    public abstract void EndState(StateMachine stateMachine);
}

public class StateMachine : MonoBehaviour {
    //Stuff here to execute the current state, store previous state, revert states, etc. 
    //Example:
    private State currentState;
    private State previousState;
    public virtual void SwitchState(State newState) {
        //Switch state, store previous state if not null
        if (currentState != null) {
            previousState = currentState;
            currentState.EndState(this);
        }        
        currentState = newState;
        currentState.BeginState(this);
    }
}
```

The idea is that these can then be inherited and expanded to work for a human ai, zombie ai, robot ai, etc:

```
public class Idle : State
{
    //Begin, Update, and End states here. Example:
    public override void BeginState(ZombieStateMachine ZSM)
    {
        Debug.Log("Begin idling");
    }
}

public class ZombieStateMachine : StateMachine {
    public Idle idleState = new Idle();
    void Start {
        SwitchState(idleState);
    }
}
```

The problem arises with the Idle state that inherits from the abstract State class. I'm trying to pass through ZombieStateMachine which inherited StateMachine, but the Idle class throws an error and instead expects StateMachine. (EDIT: The error is a compile-time error, not a run-time error as I incorrectly implied)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate on your desire to use `ZombieStateMachine` instead of `StateMachine` in the method declaration. Fact is, as the compiler's saying, you must use the exact method signature of an overridden method; only `StateMachine` would be allowed here. But the point of using abstract/polymorphism/etc. is so that callers need not know the real implementation types of the objects being used. If you want to have a compile-time restriction on the type passed to the object, then using the polymorphic approach may not be right for you. Providing more details on your real goals would help here.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use `ZombieStateMachine` instead of `StateMachine` is that all the state machines will use that framework, but inside of the `ZombieStateMachine` script will also be the unique zombie state classes, like `HuntPlayer`, `Idle`, `ClimbObject` but also within `ZombieStateMachine` will be the variables needed to move a zombie, so a `NavMeshAgent`, a `ZombieThirdPersonAnimator`, and so on.

I thought this polymorphic approach would reduce the amount of code I'd have to repeat, since otherwise I'd have to repeat the exact same `StateMachine` code for every different AI type.

Comment: Could you please post the exception?

Comment: From Unity: "Assets/_Scripts/_Zombies/ZombieStateMachine.cs(55,26): error CS0115: `Idle.BeginState(ZombieStateMachine)' is marked as an override but no suitable method found to override"

Comment: Some advice: your state machine should be _only_ that. It should maintain state. Period. Let other classes make use of the state as the state machine reports it and respond accordingly. In this way, your zombie-specific code isn't a state machine at all, but simply _composes_ a state machine. The state machine should be strictly about taking input, applying to current state, and determining the new state. With correct [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), your type conflict issues should go away.

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly the state machine should just have the basic logic necessary to determine state, and then a class outside of that, say, `ZombieAI` would call the StateMachine and have the conditional logic that checks for state and does things accordingly? (e.g., If in idle do nothing, if in hunt chase player?)

Answer (score 1):

Is this a *runtime* error as your description implies?  Or is this instead a *compile-time* error?  I suspect it's the latter, since this:

```
public override void BeginState(ZombieStateMachine ZSM)
```

doesn't actually override this:

```
public abstract void BeginState(StateMachine stateMachine)
```

The override needs to be of the same type:

```
public override void BeginState(StateMachine ZSM)
```

The idea with the Liskov Substitution Principle in this case is that nothing in the `BeginState` method should care what *kind* of `StateMachine` it's given, it should only interact with the base `StateMachine` operations.

It seems a little odd that both your base classes are passed to one another.  The methods on `State` expect a `StateMachine`, and the methods on `StateMachine` expect a `State`.  It's not really clear why that's the case.

Though if this does need to be the case, then I wonder if you might benefit from a generic base type.  Something like this:

```
public abstract class State<T> where T : StateMachine
{
    public abstract void BeginState(T stateMachine);
    public abstract void UpdateState(T stateMachine);
    public abstract void EndState(T stateMachine);
}
```

Then inherit with the specified type:

```
public class Idle : State<ZombieStateMachine>
{
    //Begin, Update, and End states here. Example:
    public override void BeginState(ZombieStateMachine ZSM)
    {
        Debug.Log("Begin idling");
    }
}
```

This is freehand code so I'm not *100%* sure it works, but it seems reasonable to me.  (If it's incorrect I'll go ahead and delete this answer.)

This *kind of* limits the pure polymorphism you're attempting, since child types can no longer accept *any* type which implements the base type.  But it looks like that's what you were expecting anyway from the usage, that a given child type of one class would essentially be "paired" with a corresponding child type of the other class.  By using generics they can be explicitly paired.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, it is a compile-time error. (I will see if your code works for me.)

Comment: I tried your code. I get a problem where inside of StateMachine, which uses State declarations, it now wants a type specified for those too. For example `public void SwitchState(State<StateMachine> newState) {}`, which when calling from `ZSM` as `SwitchState(idleState)` no longer works (since I guess idleState is of type ZSM?)

Comment: @Visulth: Ah, you're right.  This would create a kind of circular dependency.  Which I guess goes back to the question... Why do both base types need to refer to each other?  I would expect one to reference the other, but not both to mutually reference each other.  Why does a `StateMachine` need to be supplied to the methods on `State`?  I would expect a "state" to be a discrete thing in and of itself and a "state machine" would perform operations on/with a set of states.

Comment: Okay, so maybe I'm going about it the wrong way. The idea was that inside, say, The Zombie Idle state, it could reference things used in the Zombe State Machine, like a `NavMeshAgent` that wasn't a property of all `StateMachines`. I was just trying to make sure the States had references to the AI I was programming if that makes sense.

Otherwise, wouldn't the states only have like access to base information?

Comment: @Visulth: That makes sense, but I guess where the design is getting very complicated is in the notion that both sub-classes need to reference each other.  I suspect this would become much, much easier if only one of the two classes were to reference the other.  Semantically I would expect a "state" to know everything about itself and not need to reference the containing machine to get information.  It could perhaps expose operations where a containing machine can supply information when invoking actions.  But basically the state shouldn't know about the machine which contains it.

Comment: Ohh, okay. I think I understand. Thanks for clarifying why I'm running into the problem. I'll likely end up doing that if I can't find a way to implement what I want.

Comment: Note that if this is the correct approach (I'm not convinced it is), then there's no apparent point in the type being a base class at all. Instead, it should/could just be an interface.